# Connection Refused to Minio Docker instance from my Django Application

Tags: python, django, docker, minio

Hi im trying to connect to my Minio instance which is running inside a docker container from a django instance, which is also running inside a docker container.

I keep getting this error:

```
2020-10-29 13:59:17,568 urllib3.util.retry DEBUG    Incremented Retry for (url='/'): Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
2020-10-29 13:59:20,773 urllib3.connectionpool WARNING  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /
2020-10-29 13:59:20,774 urllib3.connectionpool DEBUG    Starting new HTTPS connection (6): minio:9000
```

My docker-compose file is the following:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
    db:
        container_name: db
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        ports:
          - '3306:3306'
        environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'django_dev'
          MYSQL_USER: 'user'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
        volumes:
          - ./mariadb:/var/lib/mysql

    minio:
        container_name: minio
        image: minio/minio
        command: 'server /export'
        environment: 
          MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: weak_access_key
          MINIO_SECRET_KEY: weak_secret_key
        ports:
          - '9000:9000'
        volumes:
          - ./minio:/export

    web:
        container_name: web
        build: 
          context: ./django/
          dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
          target: dev
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes: 
          - ./django:/usr/src/app
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        env_file: 
          - ./.env.dev
        depends_on:
          - minio
          - db

    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: db_viewer
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - '8080:80'
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
        depends_on:
          - db
```

The code to set up the client:

```
minioClient = Minio('minio:9000',
                  access_key='weak_access_key',
                  secret_key='weak_secret_key')
minioClient.list_buckets()
```

Im using WSL2 as development environment.

Python Version 3.7.7,
Django Version 3.1.2,
Minio Version 6.0.0

Thank you for your time.

*Edit: I reach the minio service with localhost:9000 from my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, the django minio connector tries to connect to minio using https. As you're not running minio with https, the connector errors out, cause it doesn't understand the protocol.
To fix, just set `MINIO_STORAGE_USE_HTTPS=False` (See [here](https://django-minio-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/) for the official docs) in djangos settings.py.

Comment: You were on the right track, i had to add `secure: False` to the constructor call for the Minio class. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you're working on localhost, it won't use `https`. Minio constructor's default implementation assumes that the connection is `https`.
To use `http` instead of `https`,pass `secure=False` to `Minio` constructor.

```
minioClient = Minio('minio:9000',
                  access_key='weak_access_key',
                  secret_key='weak_secret_key',
                  secure=False)
minioClient.list_buckets()
```